# Dilations are homeomorphisms with the weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis

Let E be a normed space. I want to prove that dialtions ( $ x \rightarrow \lambda x$) are homeomorphisms with the weak topology.I'm a little bit confused. What direction should I take? Should I consider an open set in $(E, \sigma(E,E^*))$ and show that its pre-image by the dilation is an open set? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What works most times...*

Consider a net $(x_\iota)_\iota$ with weak limit $x$, i.e.:
$$|f(x_\iota-x)|\stackrel{\iota}{\to}0\quad(\forall f\in E')$$

Then by linearity also:
$$|f(\lambda x_\iota-\lambda x)|=|\lambda|\cdot|f(x_\iota-x)|\stackrel{\iota}{\to}0\quad(\forall f\in E')$$

That proves continuity.

Comment: Thanks, freeze. Yesterday, talking to a professor, he gave me the same proof. But thanks for helping, dude. :)

Comment: You're welcome. ;)

Comment: Nets are particularly useful in FA as they break topology down to the level of points only not involving sets. The problem is that linear algebra is element-theoretic while topology is set-theoretic. For proofs see: [Nets in Topology](http://stijnvermeeren.be/download/mathematics/nets.pdf)